# Tailspin Spyworks Tutorial (Entity Frame Work and asp.net webforms) - Business Logic Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

During the Tailspin Spyworks tutorial (link below) the author adds a partial class for implementing some business logic. When doing this he states that this approach shouldn't really be used in a live project and that you should implement a Business Logic Layer instead.

What approaches would you suggest for this when using entity framework and asp.net webforms?

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks-part-5

http://tailspinspyworks.codeplex.com/releases/view/44512#DownloadId=119611 - download source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having a class file within the same project, one approach would be to have a separate project which compiles to a separate assembly. This would contain your entity framework goodies and a business layer to perform the CRUD.

The main website project would then reference this assembly. You could then deploy the project in a multi-tiered scenario.